# delegate.Invoke and delegate.BeginInvoke - used on the same method, return two different results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, timer

I'm writing a software that communicates with 4 devices via serial port. One of them, Input/output module (ICP CON) has 4 input channels (DL) and 4 output channels (RL). I need to monitor status of DL channels and then, when a signal is detected I have to do some processing, which depends on which signal has been detected.

I'm calling 4 methods asynchronously, every 500ms (timer), here's the tick event:

```
//stop the timer
timer1.Stop();

//open com port 2
Tester.Devices.ICP.OpenICPPort(2, 9600);

//dl 0
ic = new CheckDLStatus(0, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl 1
ic = new CheckDLStatus(1, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl 2
ic = new CheckDLStatus(2, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl3 
ic = new CheckDLStatus(3, this);
ic.Execute();

//close com port 2
Tester.Devices.ICP.CloseICPPort(2);

//enable the timer again
timer1.Enabled = true;

public CheckDLStatus(int DL, Form1 F1)
{
    //form 1 instance
    f1 = F1;

    // setup the delegate to call
    switch (DL)
    {
        case (0):
        {
            checkDL_delegate = new checkDL(
                BusinessLogicLayer.Classes.
                DevicesCommunication.CheckDl0);

            break;
        }
        case (1):
        {
            checkDL_delegate = new checkDL(
                BusinessLogicLayer.Classes.
                DevicesCommunication.CheckDl1);

                break;
        }
        case (2):
        {
            checkDL_delegate = new checkDL(
                BusinessLogicLayer.Classes.
                DevicesCommunication.CheckDl2);

                break;
        }
        case (3):
        {
            checkDL_delegate = new checkDL(
                BusinessLogicLayer.Classes.
                DevicesCommunication.CheckDl3);

                break;
        }
    }
}


public static void CheckDl2()
{
    //declare
    bool currentStatus;

    try
    {
        //input
        currentStatus = DevicesCommunication.Dl_2_On; 
        //should be false at the start of the test, 
        //so when it becomes true, the change is detected immediately

        //dl2?
        if (ICP.LookForSignal_DL2((short)2, 
            Util.Classes.Util.ResolveComPortNumber(
                Cache.settings.icpModulePort),     
            Convert.ToInt32(Cache.settings.icpModuleBaudRate)))
        {
            //signal detected
            DevicesCommunication.Dl_2_On = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //signal not detected
            DevicesCommunication.Dl_2_On = false;
        }

        //check, if status of DL2 has been changed 
        //(from true to false, from false to true)
        if (currentStatus != DevicesCommunication.Dl_2_On)
        {
            //status from before checking signal is different
            // from status read from the device so
            //status has changed

            if (DevicesCommunication.Dl_2_On)
            {
                DevicesCommunication.DL2_apperancesCounter += 1;

                //TODO
                //process
                //ProcessDL2();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //status did not change
            //just clear buffer
            ClearBuffer();
        }

        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Util.Classes.ErrorLogging.LogError(ex, true);
        //EndCurrentTest(); 
        return;
    }
}
```

`Execute()` method, that invokes a delegate:

```
public void Execute()
{
    // call the method on the thread pool
    checkDL_delegate.BeginInvoke(
        this.CallBack, null);

    //checkDL_delegate.Invoke();
}
```

The method that is called for checking DL2 status:

```
public static bool LookForSignal_DL2(short DL_number, int port, int baudRate)
{
    //declare
    bool iBit;

    try
    {
        //check if there is a signal at specified Dl_number
        iBit = DCON.Read_DI_Bit(Convert.ToByte(port), 1, -1, 
            DL_number, 16, 0, 100);

        //return resposne
        return iBit; //true/false
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Util.Classes.ErrorLogging.LogError(ex, true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I turn on signal on DL2 channel, and I call `LookForSignal_DL2` like this, without the timer and asynchronous calls (just for test):

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICP.OpenICPPort(2, 9600);

    if (ICP.LookForSignal_DL2(2, 2, 9600))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("True");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("false!");
    }

    ICP.CloseICPPort(2);
}
```

It works - returns true.

If, in `Execute()` method I use `Invoke`, which makes the method call synchronous - it works (returns true), but this way I can only check 1 signal at the time.

If, in `Execute()` method I use `BeginInvoke` it doesn't work, it returns false, even though there is signal in DL2.

I admit I don't know what's going on. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is `this.Callback`?

Comment: private void CallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            
           checkDL_delegate.EndInvoke(ar);
           

            updateStatus_delegate = new updatestatus(f1.UpdateDLStatus);

            if (f1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                f1.Invoke(updateStatus_delegate);
            }
            else
            {
                f1.UpdateDLStatus();
            }
        }

Comment: And what does the `CheckDLStatus` method do? It would *really* help if you could update your question to include *all* of the code you're calling.

Comment: BeginInvoke() returns immediately and doesn't block, this means it doesn't wait for DL2 signal and LookForSignal_DL2 returns false. Tell me if i'm wrong.

Comment: When it returns false in async mode .. is there an error recorded in your log? I notice you return false on error .. maybe throw the exception until you track it down?

I'll admit its been some years since I did serial port stuff and it was in .net 2 ... but what i remember is opening the port then waiting for an event to be fired telling me that a signal had arrived. Your method of polling the port seems a little odd to me .. but then I do not know your system requirements ... just thought I'd mention it in case you are taking a complex route to do something simple (as I often have :) )

Comment: @Arie I'm not sure because when I set break points at BeginInvoke and "iBit = DCON.Read_DI_Bit(Convert.ToByte(port), 1, -1, DL_number, 16, 0, 100);" in LookForSignal_DL2 it gets there, and DCON.Read_DI.Bit is being executed, and at this time DL2 signal is on, so shouldn't it return true?

Comment: @iDevForFun no, there is no error recorded in my error logs, and I'd notice it because my LogError method always displays an exception. For communication with the module I use SDK provided by its manufacturer, which is supposed to handle sending/receiving commands for me, and it seems to be working, because it does return correct value indicating the signal status, only not when I'm using beginInvoke...

Comment: Voting to close as it's a ["fix my code"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions) question.

Comment: I have already figured it out, but I can't post an answer yet, since I have reputation less than 100. I will in 5 hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if it helps anyone, I made a mistake here (bold text):

```
//stop the timer
timer1.Stop();

//open com port 2
Tester.Devices.ICP.OpenICPPort(2, 9600);

//dl 0
ic = new CheckDLStatus(0, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl 1
ic = new CheckDLStatus(1, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl 2
ic = new CheckDLStatus(2, this);
ic.Execute();

//dl3 
ic = new CheckDLStatus(3, this);
ic.Execute();
```

**Tester.Devices.ICP.CloseICPPort(2);**

I ran my methods asynchronously, but the execution of the code went on, and everytime the port had been closed before any of the methods was able to check for signal. Unfortunetely the SDK library doesn't return any error in that case, so it just kept returning false.

Thank you for your comments.